# how to set Positioning of nodes in Pack Layout

Tags: d3.js

I have just started using d3.js.I want to understand how pack layout positions the node.

For ex.
If I pass an array to it than it calculates position of nodes automatically.But I want it some different positions for the node not the one which is calculated by pack layout.

Comment: If you want to set different positions, set the `x` and `y` attributes of the respective data items.